# Thymeleaf: clickable row

Tags: html, hyperlink, thymeleaf

I want to generate clickable table rows within html + thymeleaf, but I have the following problem. AFAIK it's not able to wrap a tr element with a link (a-tag), because a table can only 
directly contain tr-subtags. So I have to wrap the content of each td-tag, but these values are dynamically created by thymeleaf!

What would be the best approach to link each row (link each td-tag of each row) to a generated url? Is there some th:text - prefix/suffix functionality?

```
<tr th:each="item : ${itmes}">
    <td th:text="${{item.name}}">some name</td>
    <td th:text="${{item.date}}">01.03.2014</td>
    <td>author</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{/backend/items/{id}(id=${item.id})}" href="show.html"
           role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
        </a>
        <a th:href="@{/backend/items/{id}/update(id=${item.id})}" role="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least problematic way to do this is using javascript to create each row clickable.

for e.g.

```
$("#yourtablename tr").click(function() {
            //do more javascript code to meet your needs
      });
```

Personally i would attach a href to one of the tds then do something like below:

```
$("#yourtablename tr").click(function() {
                window.location = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').attr("href");
          });
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 19):

I had to solve pretty similar problem with Tymeleaf, and I've also been needed  to pass request parameter from item to the url, so I solved like this:

```
<tr th:each="item : ${itmes}" style="cursor: pointer"
     th:onclick="'javascript:rowClicked(\'' + ${item.someField} + '\');'">
    ...
    <td>Some data</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

then include somehow the script:

```
<script>
    function rowClicked(value) {
        location.href = "/myurl?param=" + value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer is a great hack, but the fact that you need to do something so elementary is very frustrating.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me because of the onclick, I used this instead:
th:attr="onclick=|rowClicked('${item.somefield}')|"
and it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

For the latest thymeleaf version, answer by @Andrew will not work due to the [following issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/705). The code will have to be modified as follows:

```
<tr th:each="item : ${itmes}" style="cursor: pointer"
     th:some-field="${item.someField}" onclick="rowClicked(this.getAttribute('some-field'))">
    ...
    <td>Some data</td>
    ...
</tr>
```