# Thymeleaf : passing javascript parameters

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
I want to pass an attribute of a POJO to a javascript function:

```
   <tr th:each="company: ${companies}" >                                                
         <td class="col_actions">
           <a th:href="@{/company/edit/{id}(id=${company.id})}" style="color:#808080; margin-right: 10px;">
             <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </a>
           <a href="#" style="color:#808080;  text-align: center;" onclick="javascript:confirmDelete ({id}(id=${company.id}));">
              <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
            </a>
         </td>
   </tr>
```

But I got an error:  `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem came from anchor, so please try this one if the `confirmDelete()` function require a string id

```
th:onclick="'javascript:confirmDelete(\'' + ${company.id} + '\');'"
```

And if it need a number id

```
th:onclick="'javascript:confirmDelete(' + ${company.id} + ');'"
```

Comment: Might not work for the latest version of thymeleaf, please refer the answer I posted to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64884416/5105263

Answer (score 8):

Another way - `th:onclick="|confirmDelete('${company.id}')|"`

Or if you want send several params across '_' use `th:onclick="|confirmDelete('${type}_${company.id}')|"`

Answer (score 5):

This works for me, easy and clear to use [[  ]]

Use a link:

```
<a href="#" id="editUserButton" th:onclick="editUser([[${user.getId}]])">Edit</a>
```

Use a button:

```
<button type="button" id="editUserButton" class="btn btn-primary"  th:onclick="editUser([[${user.getId}]])">Edit</button>
```

Pass multiple parameters:

```
<button type="button" id="editUserButton" class="btn btn-primary" th:onclick="editUser([[${user.getId}]],[[${user.getLastName}]])">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found so many `solutions` that do not help me.

This is working for me.

```
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <button th:attr="onclick='addToBasket(\'' + ${product.getId()}+  '\');'"> add to basket
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG... thank goodness... I too have found innumerable "solutions" to this problem and none of them worked... except for this one. This is the very best answer to this question of how to pass a model variable from Thymeleaf to a JavaScript function. Applause.