# Thymeleaf/JavaScript Parameters

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I've been using SO for a while now and found solutions to most of my problems, but now I have a question concerning one of the answers i found.
(Original post: [Thymeleaf: clickable row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484706/thymeleaf-clickable-row))

The second answer provides a formidable solution to my problem but I would really like to understand how and why it works.

> ```
> <tr th:each="item : ${itmes}" 
>      th:onclick="'javascript:rowClicked(\'' + ${item.someField} + '\');'">
>     ...
>     <td>Some data</td>
>     ...
> </tr>
> ```

What are the `\''` and `'\'` characters here for and why does the parameter passing not work without them? I tried googling beforehand but didn't find anything particularly useful, but that might also be because I didn't ask the right questions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point is to generate a string that comes out like this:

```
rowClicked('somefield');
```

It's built from three strings that are concatenated together with the `+` operator:

```
'rowClicked(\''

${item.someField}

'\');'
```

The first and last parts are strings enclosed by single quotes `'`, however since you need a single quote in your output, the `\'` (which represents an escaped single quote) is added -- so the the first string is `rowClicked('` and the last `');`.  After, everything is concatenated together: `rowClicked('somefield');`

There are some alternatives that I think are easier to read.  For example, you can use [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) instead and it would look like this:

```
th:onclick="|rowClicked('${item.someField}');|"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I find there are too many quotes. Enough quotes are needed so you end up with

```
th:onclick="'javascript:rowClicked('someString');"
```

actually you can drop the `javascript:` label and just have

```
th:onclick="'rowClicked(\'' + ${item.someField} + '\');"
```

This is assuming some quotes we cannot see in your example.

I would personally set a data-attribute to the item.somefield and have

```
th:onclick="rowClicked(this);"
```

and in rowClicked have

```
function rowClicked(row) {
  var val = row.getAttribute("data-item");
```

Comment: I figured i could drop the javascript label, but if i drop the \ 's I can't pass the model attributes.   
For more context: the table basically displays all employees and the boss can change their salary with a pop up modal (Semantic UI) and to prefill the input field for the ID and Salary I use JavaScript. 

I also tried the "rowClicked(this);" but it didnt work and throws a parsing error.

Comment: If you can do `th data-item="${item.someField}"` then you should be able to not even have the onclick on the row but add it using DOM addEventListener